# Spell-checking in question titles

Tags: feature-request, status-norepro, asking

> Crossposted on Meta Stack Overflow:
>
> [**Enable spell check on title, search and tag input element**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78230/enable-spell-check-on-title-search-and-tag-input-element)

I notice that I'm the only person on Gaming to misspell achievements in a question title: [Super Meat Boy no-death achievements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14043/super-meat-boy-no-death-acheivements)

This prevents my question from being searched for (try searching for the misspelled 'acheivements' and only my question pops up).

I haven't corrected the title yet to show that in both the preview and edit boxes there seems to be no spell-checking for question titles (notice the misspelling in the Title box):

[image: Screen cap of the editing box]

Can this feature be added?

**Edit:** I corrected my question title, the screencap is enough to show what the old problem was.

**Sidenote:** Related is spell-checking in the search box, but I'll submit that as another feature request.

Comment: That's something browsers are supposed to support :) besides, now _all_ users can propose edits.

Comment: Aha, so it's not stackexchanges fault. But is there anything UI-wise that could be changed in order to help the browser realize that it should be spell-checking in there? I'm assuming they are two kinds of text boxes and only one gets a spell-checker.

Comment: A related general feature from Meta Stack Overflow: [Please add a spell checker to the markdown editor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3932/please-add-a-spell-checker-to-the-markdown-editor).

Comment: @Grace Thank you, should the question be closed and a link to the related feature be posted?

Comment: Can you provide perhaps a screenshot of the question body getting spellchecked but not the title block? And, no, this probably shouldn't be closed because you're asking less for in-engine spellchecking and more for better browser spellcheck support. So, to make this a more appealing feature-request, we should provide pictoral evidence that the spellcheck support is indeed lacking in this department.

Comment: @Grace Chrome (maybe Firefox too?) only spell checks `textarea` fields, ignoring the single line `input` ones. However, it would be incorrect to have the title use a `textarea`. SO already "does it wrong" with comments, no need to make it worse.

Comment: @badp Hmm... if that's the case... and I do agree that making the Title a `textarea` would be unwise. You should post that as an answer.

Comment: Okay, so this is my browser's fault and arguably I should be responsible for changing my settings if that's a feature I want. As an answer can someone post a way to fix this in Firefox? I know very little about configuring my browser.

Comment: Now posted as a MSO `[feature-request]`: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78230/enable-spell-check-on-title-search-and-tag-input-element - go support it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chrome (maybe Firefox too?) only does spell checking on `textarea` fields, ignoring the single line `input` ones.

It would be however incorrect to have the title use a `textarea` control. The software already abuses this tag with comments, [causing some amount of trouble](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63644/pressing-enter-in-comment-box-unexpectedly-submits-form), [and then some more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66646/confirming-context-menu-entries-via-enter-when-entering-comments-triggers-comment). There's no need to make it worse.

Besides, right now *anybody on the internet* who is offended by your typo may now submit an edit proposal to correct it. (This feature isn't yet official, or complete, or announced, but is nonetheless enabled as the team figures out how people actually would use it.)

Comment: Firefox too, indeed. *However,* in Firefox at least (not sure about Chrome), there is a 'Check Spelling' option in the context menu that overrides any settings and turns on (or off) spell check. You can also override browser defaults on the 'developer side' with [`spellcheck`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/controlling_spell_checking_in_html_forms) attribute

Comment: @YiJ Yup, same on Chrome :) That smells of a feature request!

Comment: In Safari, right-click in a text input and choose Spelling and Grammar > Check Spelling While Typing to enable for all text inputs.